# Two forms in Jquery slider validation problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using a jquery slider and in the slider I have two forms. when a user selects form number one, the link will be like this: www.webx.com/form-test.asp#1 and when they select form two the link will be www.webx.com/form-test.asp#2 . So basically the ID in the url changes depending on the form selected. Now I would like to create a jquery or javascript validation depending on what form the user had selected. So if the user selects form one (www.webx.com/form-test.asp#1) the validation only works on form number 1. Form 1 and 2 got different fields as well... Form 1 got txtname and txtsurname and form 2 got txtname, txtsurname, txtaddress... Any help please? THANKS

```
     <form action="https://www1.gotomeeting.com/en_US/island/webinar/registration.flow" method="post"  id="formElem1"  name="formElem1" autocomplete='off'>                       


            <input type="hidden" name="Template" value="https://www1.gotomeeting.com/island/webinar/registration.tmpl">
            <input type="hidden" name="Form" value="webinarRegistrationForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="WebinarKey" value="782136264">
            <input type="hidden" name="ViewArchivedWebinar" value="false">
            <input type="hidden" name="registrant" value="">

                            <tr>
<td>
                               <label for="Name_First">First Name:</label></td><td>
                                <input type="text" name="Name_First" id="Name_First" value="" class="required" maxlength="128"  /></td>
</tr>
                            <tr>
<td>
                               <label for="Name_Last">Last Name:</label></td><td>
                                <input type="text" name="Name_Last" id="Name_Last" value="" class="required" maxlength="128" /></td>
</tr>
                            <tr>
<td>
                                <label for="Email">Email Address:</label></td><td>
                                <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" value="" maxlength="128" /></td>
</tr>

                             <tr>
       <p class="submit">
                                <button id="registerButton" type="submit">Register</button></td>
</tr>

                        </form>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $( 'form#form1' ).submit(function(){
         var error = false;
         var msg = '';
        if( $( '#form1 #inputname' )=='' ){ error=true; msg='Please insert a name.<br />'; }
        /* etc */
        if( error ){
            $( '#msg' ).html( msg );
            return false;
        }
    });
    /* same for #form2 */
```

Comment: this is not working...maybe i need to change something in the code please?

Comment: what i need to put instead of form#form1 and #form1 #inputname please??

Comment: The ids of the forms and the input fields. (without any code, i can't give further help)

Comment: do you have an email so ill send you the code please? thanks for your help

Comment: don't post it all, just the important parts –> the forms

Comment: Hi Alex,I edited my post as you can see above... I had inserted the form... Can you please help me how I can do the validation?